# Crypt passwords in the DB

Tags: php, passwords, bcrypt

I was looking about best practice for password protect, everybody are talking about **bcrypt** and others hashing classes. But I can't get how To verify password if it contains *unique random salt* .

For **cookies** its fine, but without em - each time would be unique crypted value, how can I verify users password with random values? Oo . Or **bcrypt** only for **cookies**? 
Then what I should do with password in db?

Please describe to me my mistakes - what I've lost when learning about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bcrypt algorithm creates a random salt that is stored as part of the hash in a standardised way.

See [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) for a working example.

See also:

- [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

(edited heavily since my answer was wrong before)

Comment: 10x.Just join (random data+crypted pass) ? And to verify script is going to take chunk of the pass, without salt and checks it with passed data? I was trying to use **bcrypt** but I have to generate unique hash each time and pass into _check()_ function, it means each time would be random hash, am I right? I know hash should be refreshed each time, but how it checks for a valid if every time should be random?

Comment: Why would you need an additional salt on top of the one used for `bcrypt`?

Comment: @Jack you don't.  Maybe you're misunderstanding my answer?

Comment: @Jack removed one mention of salt that might have been confusing.

Comment: "You store a random salt for each user in the database along with their hashed password" - that's unnecessary with bcrypt, because the hash already contains the salt.

Comment: @Jack, you're quite right, that teaches me for answering questions on topics I'm not familiar with!  Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a group of function in the next php version, for details see [the accepted RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash).

Anthony, the author of the RFC and the patch was kind enough to provide a [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) written in php so you can start using this new functionality now!

Behind the scenes it uses crypt with the strongest algorythm currently known.

Comment: Tell me please how does the password with random salt could be verify?? My server php is only 5.2 what's your recipe in that case?

Comment: The library I linked has a function for that called `password_verify`. You should update your server, php5.3 is already 5 years old, and support for 5.2 ended two years ago.